# Reuse tasks in airflow

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, bigdata, airflow, orchestration

I'm trying out airflow for orchestrating some of my data pipelines. I'm having multiple tasks for each ingestion pipeline. The tasks are getting repeated across multiple ingestion pipelines. How can I reuse a task across DAGS in airflow?

Answer (score 3):

- Just like [`object` is an instance of a `class`](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/1257326/why-is-class-called-the-factory-of-objects), an Airflow **task is an instance of an [`Operator`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#operators) (strictly speaking, [`BaseOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py))**
- So write a "re-usable" (aka generic) operator and use it 100s of times across your pipeline(s) simply by passing different params (particularly `task_id`)

Comment: You can group similar tasks into a sudag.